# В Android studio пропал тип просмотра проекта Android. Как вернуть?

Tags: android-studio

В Android studio пропал тип просмотра проекта Android. Произошел какой-то сбой в android studio. Очистил кэш. Подскажите пожалуйста как вернуть тип просмотра Android?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Заменил строку в файле .iml
Строка для замены

```
<orderEntry type="jdk" jdkName="1.8" jdkType="JavaSDK" />
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]